# Undefined prop in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have a parent component containing three child components. The first child component is a form. On a submit event it passes data to both the second and third child components via the parent component using props. However in one of the child components, the prop is always undefined. I think it's a timing issue, but using v-if does not seem to solve the issue.

The Parent Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <patents-searchform v-on:form-submit="processForm"></patents-searchform>
        <patents-word-cloud
          v-if="searched"
          v-show="searched"
          :patentsQuery="patentsQuery"
          :livePage="livePage"
          v-on:pageChange="handlePageChange"
        />
        <patents-search-results
          v-if="searched"
          v-show="searched"
          ref="resultsRef"
          :livePage="livePage"
          :results="patentsQueryResult"
          v-on:pageChange="handlePageChange"
    </div>
</template>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            livePage: 1,
            searched: false,
            queryform: 'initVal',
            patentsQueryResult: {},
            searching: false,
            patentsQuery: {}
        };
    },
    components: {
        'patents-searchform': PatentsSearchForm,
        'patents-searchresults': PatentsSearchResults,
        'patents-word-cloud': PatentsWordCloud,
    },
    methods: {
        handlePageChange(value) {
            console.log('Homepage::handlePageChange', value)
            this.queryform.page = value;
            this.livePage = value;
            this.fetchData();
        },
        processForm(formData) {
            this.queryform = formData;
            this.fetchData();
            this.patentsQuery['query'] = this.queryform['query']
            this.patentsQuery['searchMode'] = this.queryform['searchMode']
            this.searched = true;
        },
        fetchData() {
            const path = '/flask/searchPatentsNEW';
            this.searching = true;
            if (this.queryform !== 'initVal') {
                axios.post(path, this.queryform)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.patentsQueryResult = res.data;
                        this.searching = false;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The child component (PatentSearchResults) in which the props work correctly:

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-card>
          <a id="sTitleCard">Search Results</a>
          <div id="quickStats" style="margin-left: 5%" v-if="this.results.stats">
            {{results.stats.totalAuthors}} inventors across {{results.stats.docCount}} patents
            ({{results.stats.totalQueryTime}} seconds)
          </div>
    </b-card>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Results',
  props: ['results', 'livePage'],
  computed: {
    thisAuthorPage() {
      if (this.results.authors !== null) {
        return this.results.authors; //this.results works fine
      }
      console.log('no authors')
      return [];
    },
  },
  methods: {
  },  
};
</script>
```

And the child component where the props are undefined:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <b-card id="patentWordCloudCard" bg-variant="light">
        <b-container>
            <b-form id="queryForm" @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" novalidate>
                <b-row class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <b-button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" variant="primary">Generate query word cloud</b-button>
                </b-row>
            </b-form>
        </b-container>
    </b-card>
    
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: 'Patents Word Cloud',
    props: ['patentsQuery'],
    data() {
        return{
            form: {
                query: this.patentsQuery.query,
                searchMode: this.patentsQuery.searchMode
            },
            show: true,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.patentsQuery) //undefined
    },
    computed() {
        console.log(this.patentsQuery) //undefined
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.patentsQuery) //undefined
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Is it a timing issue where the word cloud component is mounted before patentsQuery is defined? If so, why did v-if not delay the component, as searched is false until after patentsQuery is defined.

Comment: The `v-if` and `v-show` of `patents-word-cloud` have the wrong syntax. One of them is also missing a quote.

Comment: `patentsQuery` is initialised to an empty object. On page load it should not be `undefined`. I don't see it being overwritten anywhere either. The component has a weird `computed() { ... }` function, but unless the compiler complains about it and just doesn't update the component that should not be a problem. If you don't see an empty object if you remove the `v-if`/`v-show` you can likely rule out `patents-searchform` entirely. Does it still say `undefined` instead of an empty object even if you comment that component out entirely?

Comment: if I completely comment out the search form component and the v-if, v-show attributes, I still get undefined when trying to access patentsQuery on mounted or computed, or from within the onSubmit method in the PatentsWordCloud component. patentsQuery while initialized as an empty object, is supposed to overwritten within the processForm method in the PatentsPage, same as patentsQueryResult.

Comment: Also @Sumurai8 thanks for catching those errors, they're not in the actual code just me being careless when copying it over to my question. I've edited them

Answer (score 0):

It was a timing issue, I was able to access patentsQuery with the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <b-card id="patentWordCloudCard" bg-variant="light">
        <b-container>
            <b-form id="queryForm" align-h="center" @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" novalidate>
                <b-row align-h="center">
                    <b-button align-h="center" id="btnSubmit" type="submit" variant="primary">Generate query word cloud</b-button>
                </b-row>
            </b-form>
            
        </b-container>
    </b-card>
    
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';


export default {
    name: 'Patents Word Cloud',
    props: ['patentsQuery'],
    methods: {
        onSubmit(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            const path = 'flask/patentWordCloud';
            this.searching = true
            axios.post(path, this.patentsQuery).then((res) => {
                    console.log('Patent Word Cloud Data')
                    console.log(res.data)
                    this.patentResults = res.data;   
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```